# on_form_prefill delete all fields values if it executes form.process

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I want to override the form of the `Matriline` model shown below.

First I add an extra field `clan`, and in `on_form_prefill` I reset this field's choices and default (just testing).

Without calling `form.process` the choices are set to my new options, but the default option is not selected.

If calling `form.process` the choices are set to my new options and the default option is selected, but all the other fields are deleted.

Anybody can help?

**views.py**

```
class MatrilineAdmin(sqla.ModelView):

    form_extra_fields = {
        'clan': SelectField('Clan',
            coerce=int,
            choices=[ (c.id, c.name) for c in Clan.query.all()])
    }
    create_template = 'admin/create.html'
    edit_template = 'admin/edit.html'

    def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
        form.clan.choices = [(1, "first"),(2,"second")]
        form.clan.default = 2
        form.process() # if commented, set choices but does not set default
                       # else set choices and default but delete all the other fields values (name and pod_id)
```

**models.py**

```
class Matriline(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'matriline'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    calls = db.relationship('Call', backref='matriline', lazy='select')
    pod_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pod.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pod(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pod'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    matrilines = db.relationship('Matriline', backref='pod', lazy='select')
    clan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clan.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Clan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clan'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    pods = db.relationship('Pod', backref='clan', lazy='select')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620219/setting-a-default-on-a-select-removes-the-settings-passed-in-to-populate-the-for

Comment: @user2990084: From at WTForms point of view it is clear that we ought to pass defaults to the constructor. When using flask_admin this is sometimes not an option as the form is generated up-front and cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by [process_data](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.process_data)

```
def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
    form.clan.choices = [(1, "first"), (2, "second")]
    form.clan.process_data(2)
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar problem and made it work by re-processing only the changed field. Also I needed to pass the currently set value in again (else it would be always set to the default):

```
from wtforms.utils import unset_value

class CustomView:
    def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
        form.clan.choices = [(1, "first"),(2,"second")]
        form.clan.default = 2
        form.clan.process(None, form.clan.data or unset_value)
```

*NOTE: As `on_form_prefill` is only called in the `edit_view` and not in the `create_view` this does only work with existing instances.*

Comment: Thank you for this. This solved my problem with overriding edit_form to use a custom form.